# Apache Error - AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have checked my Apache error log and found the following errors:

> [Tue Mar 13 05:04:47.855612 2018] [core:error] [pid 18177] [client
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal
>   redirects due to probable configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

This is a copy of my `.htaccess` file:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch ".(js|css|xml|gz|html)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Apache 2.4.27

PHP 7.0.27

Can anyone suggest what i need to change?

Comment: Read your message: `Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace`.  do that, look at the logs, if still unclear, post the debug info in the question.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem caused by this line :

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
```

So , get this `?` out between `^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)` and `(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)` like this :

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
```

Because , `a?c`  will match against `ac` as well as `a` and at your case if a URI is starting with `wp-admin` it will match in two rules , first with this `RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]` and then with this and that why error happened.

**Note:** clear browser cache then test it .

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error, but the cause was different. I had added a bad rewrite rule with `add_rewrite_rule()`. After saving the new permalink structure, this line was added to `.htaccess`

`RewriteRule ^ / [QSA,L]`

This broke the website and WP wouldn't load in order for me to rebuild the new permalink structure even after commenting out my bad code. I tried using the wp CLI tool `wp rewrite flush --hard`, but for that to work, I needed a `wp-cli.local.yml` file in my WP project folder (the one with `wp-config.php` in it) with the following content:

```yaml
apache_modules:
    - mod_rewrite
```

I could then do the rewrite flush and get back into my site. Checking the apache2 error log was of no help to me in this case - but YMMV.

Had I known all this, I could have just deleted the offending line from `.htaccess` but since I don't really understand RewriteRules file, I didn't know it was at fault.